# Storing static configuration/lookup data in Rails DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, psql

Let's say I have a feature that let's user's delete their profile from my app. But before they go, I ask them to fill out a reason why they're leaving ("too much email", "no longer using the service", "other", etc...)

I'd like to store the reason for leaving in a field on my `User` model - `User#reason`

My question is, where/how do I store my enumerated list of reasons? I see a few options, hoping to get advice on what others have used and which is the most "Rails way" to do it.

1. Store as plaintext - As described above, store the full text for the reason in `User#reason`. However each time I update a particular phrasing for a reason, I'll have to patch all the existing values as well.
2. Static configuration table. Create a static table / model called `Reason` and store a list of reasons. Then each `User` model will have a foreign key reference to a `reason_id`. The problem is that I can't easily delete reasons if I choose to because of foreign key dependencies.
3. [ActiveHash](https://github.com/zilkey/active_hash) - Seems like it was made for this sort of thing. An in-memory hash that functions like an `ActiveRecord` object. However once again, if any of the Id's change (and they easily can because they're stored in the code, not the DB, and anyone in my organization could change them) it would mess with the foreign key mapping in other tables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a joining table, something like UsersReasons which has two foreign keys, user_id and reason_id. Then you have a Reason model backed by a reasons table and everything is linked using foreign keys.

Have a look at Rails' `has_many_through` documentation for how to wire the models up: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have `User` and `Reason` model available.

I would prefer to go for a line item table say `user_reasons`(`UserReason` model) with `user_id` and `reason_id` as columns.

`User` can have `has_one` `user_reason`

& `Reason` can have `has_many` `user_reasons`

Each time a user gives a reason before opting out, it will be stored in `user_reasons` table.